# Pass global javascript variables to php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a index.php file where I have canvas game. This game is loaded from separate game.js file where I have variable: ballsCought. I want this wariable and name inputet to text input pass on click to another php file. my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple Canvas Game</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            function score(){
                $('#score').fadeIn(1000);
                $('#score').load("load_players.php");
            };

            setInterval(score , 1000);

            var nam = $("#name").val();         

            $('#submit').keyup(function(e){
                if(e.keyCode == 13){
                $.post('upload_score.php','n=' +nam, 'score=' +ballsCought);
                }
            });

            $('#submit').click(function(e){
                $.post('upload_score.php','n=' +nam, 'score=' +ballsCought);
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<script src="game.js"></script>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="525" height="525"></canvas>
    <br /><p><span id="points"></span><input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name..."/><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
    <br /><span id="score"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

But this post function is not working any idea? THank you...

Comment: Why dont you put the value of that variable in a hidden field and then pass that value from that hidden field to another page where you want it.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I tried to do it. To put variable value into hidden but I can't make it work, it's not passing. Still returning 0. This code: $("#points_hidden").html(ballsCaught);

points_hidden is the hidden field and this line is inside game.js file

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your $.post method is not correct. If you want to pass data to the PHP page you need to use the JavaScript object notation like so:

```
$.post('upload_score.php', {n: nam, score: ballsCought});
```

You can read more about the various ways to call $.post from the [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) page

Now there could still be problems with your PHP page. You should use something like Firebug to see the Ajax request and any errors that might be returned.